# can't mix plural and singluar during NSG creation?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I'm wondering if anyone has experience in this. I'm trying to come up with a standard NSG module, and pass in NSG rules as paramters tfvar file, and get it created.

this is my NSGrule.tf

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "nsgrule" {
  for_each                    = var.network_security_rules
  name                        = each.value.name
  description                 = each.value.description
  priority                    = each.value.priority
  direction                   = each.value.direction
  access                      = each.value.access
  protocol                    = each.value.protocol
  source_port_range           = each.value.source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = each.value.destination_port_range
  source_address_prefix       = each.value.source_address_prefix
  destination_address_prefix  = each.value.destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name
}
```

this is my parameter file

```
network_security_rules = {

 IN-syslogProxy = {
    name                       = "IN-syslogProxy"
    description                = "NSS appliance to syslog proxy"
    priority                   = 120
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "514"
    source_address_prefix      = "172.19.16.6"
    destination_address_prefix = "172.19.16.4"
 }
}
```

so it works great with single IP and single Port, but what about multiple port or multiple IPs? say if we have another rule

```
OUT-InternetServices = {
    name                       = "OUT-InternetServices"
    description                = "Allows traffic for outgoing to the Internet - until Firewalls in place - use with Caution"
    priority                   = 560
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "TCP"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_ranges    = ["80","443"]
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "Internet"
 }
```

it's going to fail, first, it's expecting destination_port_range not destination_port_ranges.
second, ["80","443"] is a list value, I don't think map type can have value of list.

how can you mix plural and singluar during NSG creation? appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could provide more arguments for the variable `network_security_rules`.

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "nsgrule" {
  for_each                    = var.network_security_rules
  name                        = each.value.name
  description                 = each.value.description
  priority                    = each.value.priority
  direction                   = each.value.direction
  access                      = each.value.access
  protocol                    = each.value.protocol

  source_port_range           = each.value.source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = each.value.destination_port_range
  source_address_prefix       = each.value.source_address_prefix
  destination_address_prefix  = each.value.destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name

  source_port_ranges          = each.value.source_port_ranges
  destination_port_ranges     = each.value.destination_port_ranges
  source_address_prefixes     = each.value.source_address_prefixes
  destination_address_prefixes  = each.value.destination_address_prefixes
}
```

If you don't specify the argument value you can set `null` in your parameter values.

```
network_security_rules = {

 IN-syslogProxy = {
    name                       = "IN-syslogProxy"
    description                = "NSS appliance to syslog proxy"
    priority                   = 120
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    source_port_ranges         = null
    destination_port_range     = "514"
    destination_port_ranges    = null
    source_address_prefix      = "172.19.16.6"
    source_address_prefixes    = null
    destination_address_prefix = "172.19.16.4"   
    destination_address_prefixes  = null
 },

OUT-InternetServices = {
    name                       = "OUT-InternetServices"
    description                = "Allows traffic for outgoing to the Internet - until Firewalls in place - use with Caution"
    priority                   = 560
    direction                  = "Outbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "TCP"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    source_port_ranges         = null
    destination_port_range     = null
    destination_port_ranges    = ["80","443"]
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    source_address_prefixes     = null
    destination_address_prefix = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefixes  = null
 }

}
```

You can declare the variable like this, refer to [this1](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html#complex-type-literals) and [this2](https://www.intrepidintegration.com/tech/how-to-reference-data-objects-with-terraform/).

```
variable "network_security_rules" {
  type = map(object({

    name                       = string
    description                = string
    priority                   = string
    direction                  = string
    access                     = string
    protocol                   = string
    source_port_range          = string
    source_port_ranges         = list(string)
    destination_port_range     = string
    destination_port_ranges    = list(string)
    source_address_prefix      = string
    source_address_prefixes    = list(string)
    destination_address_prefix = string
    destination_address_prefixes  = list(string)

  }))

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nancy! I was overthinking too much, I was trying with dynamic or trying to add if condition... but this is much simplier

Comment: Nancy, Can I ask what should the variable type be? I used map, but terraform plan is throwing error saying:The given value is not valid for variable "network_security_rules": string is
required.

Comment: how do you specify '*' equivalent using source_port_ranges only?